# Vue.js component img src from prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bind

I'm trying to do the following, but the image doesn't output correctly. Where I display the image in display.vue, if I print {{ someText }}, I get the correct file path (../assets/city.png).

display.vue

```
<template>
    <example :someText="'../assets/' + stamp + '.png'"></example>
</template>

<script>
import example from './example.vue'

export default {
    name: "",
    data() {
        return {
            stamp: "city"
        }
    }
    components: [
        example
    ]
};
</script>
```

example.vue

```
<template>
    <img :src="someText" />
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: "example",
      props: ["someText"]
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't output correctly"? Is the image showing at all?

Comment: @Stephen Thomas It shows the default image symbol.

Comment: Have you verified that the file exists in the specified location? rememet that relative urls (like the one you use) are relative to the current url location of the browser

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your props case format:

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret
> any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using
> in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents (**[source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case)**)

It should work this way:

```html
<template>
  <example :some-text="'../assets/' + stamp + '.png'"></example>
</template>
```

Comment: OP isn't using in-DOM templates, so camelCase isn't the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing happened to me also. In your **example.vue** try this

```
<template>
    <img src="../assets/city.png" />
</template>
```

If this not gives you the correct output. Then try with the full path

```
<template>
    <img src="src/assets/city.png" />
</template>
```

My case was image doesn't read from `../assets/city.png` but it reads from `src/assets/city.png`

Comment: Maybe I don't know. What I said is what worked for me. =)

Comment: Ok)). In my project work code <img src="@/assets/logo.png" />

Comment: I think different web pack versions has to have different syntax.  Anyways we both can say changing the path as you mentioned or as I mentioned should solve this question. =)